# Summarizing multiple categorical factor items together

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I am working with a Qualtrics survey, doing some data cleaning. One question is:

Please check all behaviors you use to say 'hello':

```
Waive
Smile
Say 'Hello'
```

Output is:

```
df$hello
 [1] "1,2,3"         "1,2"
 [3] "3"
```

I used splitstack function to break these numbers up.

```
library(splitstackshape)
df <- cSplit(df, "hello",",")
```

Now I have:

```
hello_01, hello_02, and hello_03
```

I'd like to summarize these items to say: 3 participants indicated 'Say Hello'; 2 participants 'Waive' and 2 participants 'Smile'

These variables have been changed to factor

I have tried:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    gather(hello_01:hello_3) %>%
    count (n = n())
```

But this has not worked. Ultimately, I want to summarize these numbers and use them in logistic regression equations etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with splitting up the values by the commata is, that you end up
with columns that contain values for different greeting types.
Any variable should represent one thing/item/concept.

Here is an example that shows how to split the values into homgenous
variables. This allows us to `count()` each greeting type and prepares
the variables for use in regression models.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Recreating you dataset
df <- 
  tibble(hello = c("1,2,3", "1,2", "3"))

# Create a variable for each type of greeting
df <- 
  df |> 
  mutate(hello_waive = str_detect(hello, "1"),
         hello_smile = str_detect(hello, "2"),
         hello_hello = str_detect(hello, "3"))

# Count participants that use types of greetings
df |> 
  count(hello_waive)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   hello_waive     n
#>   <lgl>       <int>
#> 1 FALSE           1
#> 2 TRUE            2

df |> 
  count(hello_smile)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   hello_smile     n
#>   <lgl>       <int>
#> 1 FALSE           1
#> 2 TRUE            2

df |> 
  count(hello_hello)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   hello_hello     n
#>   <lgl>       <int>
#> 1 FALSE           1
#> 2 TRUE            2

# To count all greeting types in one table you could do:
df |> 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("hello_")) |> 
  filter(value) |> 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, "hello_")) |> 
  count(name)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   name      n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 hello     2
#> 2 smile     2
#> 3 waive     2
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! The data came from Qualtrics and was set up to be commata. Because I want to use this in a regression equation, I'll need to create dichotomous items Y or N to using this particular way to say 'hi.' What additional syntax do I need to do that?

Comment: The logical variables with TRUE/FALSE values are perfect for regression. Just add each hello_ variable to your model.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(hello = c("1,2,3", "1,2", "3"))
response <- c("Waive", "Smile","Say 'Hello'")

df %>% 
  separate_rows(hello, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(response = response[as.numeric(hello)]) %>%  
  count(response)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   response [3]
#>   response        n
#>   <chr>       <int>
#> 1 Say 'Hello'     2
#> 2 Smile           2
#> 3 Waive           2
```

Comment: You could replace `group_by(response) %>% count()` with `count(response)` and then you don't have to worry about ungrouping.

Comment: @LMc sure it works. Just checked the docs. But when I was testing on this machine, it gave me an error so I doubted myself and posted the "working" version :D Lesson of the day: Never doubt yourself, lol